# I am trying to use Alamofire framework .If I try to import Alamofire,my xcode is showing me the error as below

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I got error like as below:

swift:10:8: No such module 'Alamofire'

Comment: are u open the .xcworkspace or .xcodeproj

Comment: I used to open .xcworkspace

Comment: It is showing more then 20 issues in the Alamofire framework directory in the project navigatior

Comment: can u show the error

Comment: karthik, It has cleared now and I changed the version to 2.0

Answer (score 0):

I have also same error to be showed, I think swift 2.0 support only Alamofire 2.0, so change to work its working for me,
example:

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 2.0’

hope its helpful